# Using LibGDX, how do you have an animation using seperate images ?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, animation, libgdx

I'm learning how to make games using LibGDX and I'm trying to make a small platform game (using Eclipse). I made 4 images on the main character running to make an animation when he moves. However, I can't find anything online to show me how to make an animation without using a SpriteSheet. How do you make an animation using 4 different images ?

Comment: Any reason you do not want to use a SpriteSheet?

Comment: I tried making one but didn't manage to make one that worked (the images are not the same width).

Comment: You need to have them on the same Texture to work I believe, otherwise the SpriteBatch draw operation will fail. I am not sure though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: You should not use different images. Maybe for your player it does not matter much (because there is only one) but in general you should always use sprite sheets, a.k.a. `TextureAtlas`.

However, it is possible without it by using different textures.

```
TextureRegion tex1 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("play_anim_1"));
TextureRegion tex2 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("play_anim_2"));
TextureRegion tex3 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("play_anim_3"));
TextureRegion tex4 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("play_anim_4"));

Animation playerAnimation = new Animation(0.1f, tex1, tex2, tex3, tex4);
```

Comment: I have faced the draw animation from separated imaged in libgdx JAVA. I think, your suggest is good, but i don't know how to implement that. If possible, help me...

Answer (score 2):

You should use a TexturePacker with TextureAtlas. Adding every texture by hand is not the right way.

The texture packer packs your several images into one image. Use names like this: img_01.png, img_02.png etc, and you extract them all in one line of code in an Array.

I will post code examples in a few hours when i get home.

I actually had an separate class for dealing with loading of assets:

```
public abstract class Assets {
private static AssetManager asm = new AssetManager();
private static String assetsPackPath = "assets.pack";
public static TextureAtlas atlas;

public static void load(){
    asm.load(assetsPackPath, TextureAtlas.class);
    asm.finishLoading();

    atlas = asm.get(assetsPackPath);
}

public static void dispose(){
    asm.dispose();
}
}
```

And the code that loads animation :

```
playerRun = new Animation(1/10f, Assets.atlas.findRegions("run"));
playerRun.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
```

My original animation images were run_001.png, run_002.png, ...

Because your file names have a format name_0001.png the Texture packer puts animation keyframes in one file and they all have one name "name" and a additional parameter "index" that is the number in your file name, for example 001, 002, 003, etc.

And `Assets.atlas.findRegions("run")` returns an Array with the keyframes.