# Executable jar with libgdx: asset not found

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, executable-jar, gradle-eclipse

I created a little Game using the libgdx libraries and exported it to an executable jar. In Eclipse the Game works fine but the jar crashes with:

```
PS E:\Workspaces\JavaGames\Executable Jars> java -jar Pk2.jar
SetToNewScreen called
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: img/player/player_16_down.png
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:130)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:121)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
    at org.hofrob.entities.Player.<init>(Player.java:29)
    at org.hofrob.screens.misc.Play.show(Play.java:121)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at org.hofrob.screens.Screenmanager.setToNewScreen(Screenmanager.java:63)
    at org.hofrob.pkgame.MyPkGame.create(MyPkGame.java:20)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: img\player\player_16_down.png (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:220)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
    ... 12 more
```

The problematic line is:

```
private final Sprite player_down =
    new Sprite(new Texture("img/player/player_16_down.png"));
```

I followed [the libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application) to create the jar. The assets folder is included in the build path and the content of the assets folder is in the exported jar:

- /com
- /img
- /javazoom
- /META_INF
- /net
- /org
- /tiles
- ...

I also tried using `Gdx.files.internal` (also, removing **final**)

```
private final Sprite player_down = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/player/player_16_down.png")));
```

but there was no difference.

I am able to export the basic project, which exists when a new gradle project is imported into eclipse as an executable jar (without errors when executing the jar).

Similar questions I found had the problem that the assets folder was not included in the jar, which doesn't seem to be a problem here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an "assets" directory in your generated JAR?  I can't find the code to prove this, but I believe the manifest expects an "assets" directory to exist in the JAR with the assets in it (so "assets/img/" in your case.)

Comment: There is no "assets" dir, but there is also none in the jar that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place all content of your assets folder to the same directory as jar in.

Comment: That works but it's not that pretty (imho). Is there a way to get everything into the jar?

Comment: @RoHo I found a solution to this problem. I assume that you are using Gradle but if not, those who will get this frustrating problem will be using it as of 2018. The solution I found packages all assets into the jar as you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same issue that you have a while ago. I was also using Eclipse to generate my jar files and no matter what I did the files were not found when I ran the jar file.

**The solution**:

- First navigate to the directory of your project in the command-line.
- Run the command `gradlew desktop:dist`.
- The generated jar file can be found in `desktop/build/libs`.

**Note:** Another issue that I found out about is that when you run your project in Eclipse, it is not case-sensitive about file extensions. This means that in Eclipse a project that loads in the file `img.png` in code, but is actually `img.PNG`, you will not get an error. *However, you will get an error when you run the jar file*.

I hope this answer helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

Answer (score 0):

I loaded assets a bit differently, my executable jar file runs fine. Here's my Assets class:

```
public abstract class Assets {
private static AssetManager asm = new AssetManager();
private static String assetsPackPath = "assets.pack";
public static TextureAtlas atlas;

public static void load(){
    asm.load(assetsPackPath, TextureAtlas.class);
    asm.finishLoading();

    atlas = asm.get(assetsPackPath);
}

public static void dispose(){
    asm.dispose();
}
}
```

If you are not using texture packer then you should! If interested check [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305191/using-libgdx-how-do-you-have-an-animation-using-seperate-images/25365653#25365653)

Comment: I know I should use the texture packer and will check your solution out. So far I just wanted to get something _quick and dirty_ and clean up later. I still need to work myself into the texture packer and atlas and will add a comment when I've done that.